# Combining sets of lines from two different files in a specific order in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with sets of lines that go as following (X being even numbers):

```
FRAME X
JOINT 0
POS 0
LINVEL 0 
ANGVEL 0
FRAME X+2
JOINT 0
POS 0
LINVEL 0 
ANGVEL 0
etc
```

The other file has sets of lines as following (Y being odd numbers):

```
FRAME Y
JOINT 0
POS 0
LINVEL 0 
ANGVEL 0
FRAME Y+2
JOINT 0
POS 0
LINVEL 0 
ANGVEL 0
etc
```

And I want to combine them so that I get:

```
FRAME X
JOINT 0
POS 0
LINVEL 0 
ANGVEL 0
FRAME Y
JOINT 0
POS 0
LINVEL 0 
ANGVEL 0
FRAME X+2
JOINT 0
POS 0
LINVEL 0 
ANGVEL 0
FRAME Y+2
JOINT 0
POS 0
LINVEL 0 
ANGVEL 0
etc
```

Is there an easy way to do this with Notepad++?
Here are the two files in question:
http://www.speedyshare.com/uVNJF/first-Copy.rpl

http://www.speedyshare.com/3Um8z/second-Copy.rpl

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if you can do it with `recorded macro` in Notepad++,  but I guess writing some code is more easier. What is your preferred language?

Comment: I'm completely programming illiterate unfortunately, that's why I wanted to know if there was a simple Notepad++ way of doing it, sorry :(